# Chess Engine - Confusion in engine types - Flash as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, artificial-intelligence, chess

I am not sure this kind of question has been asked before, and been answered, by as far as my search is concerned, I haven't got any answer yet.

First let me tell you my scenario.

I want to develop a chess game in Flash AS3. I have developed the interface. I have coded the movement of the pieces and movement rules of the pieces. (Please note: Only movement rules yet, not capture rules.)

Now the problem is, I need to implement the AI in chess for one player game. I am feeling helpless, because though I know each and every rules of the chess, but applying AI is not simple at all.

And my biggest confusion is: I have been searching, and all of my searches tell me about the chess engines. But I always got confused in two types of engines. One is for front end, and second is real engines. But none specifies (or I might not get it) which one is for which.

I need a API type of some thing, where when I can get searching of right pieces, and move according to the difficulty. Is there anything like that?

Please note: I want an open source and something to be used in Flash.

Thanks.

Comment: A front end engine is what deals with visuals, the back end or "real" is what operates the data hidden from view. A chess AI of yours should use your chessboard in whatever matter you can present it to the AI, and evaluate possible moves in the same terms - that's what backend engine is for. Then, once it'll choose a move, front end part comes into play, and moves the piece of the AI, displaying the result.

Comment: You may have a hard time finding one for flash but you may be able to port over an existing one from another language.

Answer (score 1):

First of all http://nanochess.110mb.com/archive/toledo_javascript_chess_3.html here is the original project which implements a relatively simple AI (I think it's only 2 steps deep) in JavaScript. Since that was a contest project for minimal code, it is "obfuscated" somewhat by hand-made reduction of the source code. Here's someone was trying to restore the same code to a more or less readable source: https://github.com/bormand/nanochess .

I think that it might be a little bit too difficult to write it, given you have no background in AI... I mean, a good engine needs to calculate more then two steps ahead, but just to give you some numbers: the number of possible moves per step, given all pieces are on the board would be approximately 140 at max, the second step thus would be all the combination of these moves with all possible moves of the opponent and again this much combinations i.e. 140 * 140 * 140. Which means you would need a very good technique to discriminate the bad moves and only try to predict good moves.

As of today, there isn't a deterministic winning strategy for chess (in other words, it wasn't solved by computers, like some other table games), which means, it is a fairly complex game, but an AI which could play at a hobbyist level isn't all that difficult to come up with.

A recommended further reading: http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/

Comment: A chess program doesn't use AI.  It searches, evaluates and prunes.  It uses hash tables to avoid duplicating evaluation, which in turn means it must use a zobrist hash to represent a board position.  A better site for further reading would be: http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/

Comment: Just another day at the office for a computer.  It's not intelligence of any sort.

Comment: No, I cannot be bothered.  However no one in the chess world uses the term *AI* when referring to a chess engine or the algorithms it performs.

Comment: I'm sure we could go back and forth until the end of time and its not that important. What is important is that for decades chess engines have approached the problem in pretty much the same way - tree searching, pruning, evaluation and hashing. Your answer covers none of this and is pretty high-level and seems to discuss how you'd solve the problem.

Comment: @wvxvw The link is _the_ source for everything around chess programming (which is of course at least partly a matter of AI). You will find almost every scientific publication about computer chess referenced there and many more general publications about game theory.

Answer (score 1):

A *Chess Program* these days comes in two parts:

- The User Interface, which provides the chess board, moves view, clocks, etc.
- The Chess Engine, which provides the ability to play the game of chess.

These two programs use a simple text protocol ([UCI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Chess_Interface) or [XBoard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBoard)) to communicate with the UI program running the chess engine as a child process and communicating over pipes.

This has several significant advantages:

- You only need one UI program which can use any compliant chess engine.
- Time to develop the chess engine is reduced as only a simple interface need be provided.

It also means that the developers get to do the stuff they are good at and don't necessarily have to be part of a team in order to get *the other bit* finished.  Note that there are many more chess engines than chess UI's available today.

You are coming to the problem with several disadvantages:

1. As you are using Flash, you cannot use this two program approach (AFAIK Flash cannot use `fork()`. `exec()`, `posix_spawn()`).  You will therefore need to provide all of the solution which you should at least attempt to make multi-threaded so the engine can work while the user is interacting with the UI.
2. You are using a language which is very slow compared to C++, which is what engines are generally developed in.
3. You have access to limited system resources, especially memory. You might be able to override this with some setting of the Flash runtime.

If you want your program to actually play chess then you need to solve the following problems:

- Move Generator: Generates all legal moves in a position.  Some engine implementations don't worry about the "legal" part and prune illegal moves some time later.  However you still need to detect check, mate, stalemate conditions at some point.
- Position Evaluation: Provide a score for a given position.  If you cannot determine if one position is *better* for one side than another then you have no way of finding winning moves.
- Move Tree and pruning: You need to store the move sequences you are evaluating and a way to prune (ignore) branches that don't interest you (normally because you have determined that they are weak).  A chess move tree is vast given every possible reply to every possible move and pruning the tree is the way to manage this.
- Transpotion table: There are many transpositions in chess (a position reached by moving the pieces in a different order). One method of avoiding the re-evaluation of the position you have already evaluated is to store the position score in a transposition table.  In order to do that you need to come up with a hash key for the position, which is normally implemented using [Zobrist hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zobrist_hashing).

The best sites to get more detailed information (I am not a chess engine author) would be:

- [TalkChess Forum](http://www.talkchess.com/forum/index.php)
- [Chess Programming Wiki](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/)

Good luck and please keep us posted of your progress!